# Kaluza Klein Equations of Motion

Tags: homework-and-exercises, general-relativity, kaluza-klein

I have found a derivation of the Kaluza-Klein equations of motion on this webpage: http://www.konfluence.org/Williams_31Mar2012.pdf

As I understand it, he starts with the 5d geodesic equation of motion
$$\tilde{U}^a \tilde{\nabla}_a \tilde{U}^b=0$$ (tildes and roman indices refer to 5d).

He asks how a 4d geodesic would move (greek indices for 4d) and finds (eqn 34):
$$\tilde{U}^a \tilde{\nabla}_a \tilde{U}^\mu=0 \Rightarrow \frac{d U^\mu}{d \tau} + \tilde{\Gamma}^\mu_{\alpha \beta} \tilde{U}^\alpha \tilde{U}^\beta + 2\tilde{\Gamma}^\mu_{5 \alpha} U^\alpha U^5 + \tilde{\Gamma}^\mu_{55} U^5U^5 + U^\mu \frac{d}{d \tau} \ln{ \left( \frac{c d \tau}{ds} \right)}=0$$ with $$\tilde{U}^a = \frac{dx^a}{ds}. U^a=\frac{dx^a}{d \tau}.$$

Question 1: where does the last term (with log) in the above equation of motion come from?

He then says that he wants to match this with standard equation of motion for particle in presence of EM field and so identifies $kU^5=\frac{q}{mc}$. Somehow this can then be rearranged to give his eqn 2:

$$\frac{d U^\mu}{d \tau} + \Gamma^\mu_{\alpha \beta} U^\alpha U^\beta =\frac{q}{mc} F^{\mu \nu} U_\nu$$

Question 2: How on earth does this substitution help bring it to this form? How do I change the $\tilde{\Gamma}$'s to $\Gamma$'s? How do I get $F^{\mu \nu}$? Where does the crazy log term go?

Comment: Minor comment to the post (v1): Please consider to mention explicitly author, title, etc. of link, so it is possible to reconstruct link in case of link rot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Observe that
   $$ \frac{\mathrm{d}\tilde{U}^\mu}{\mathrm{d}s} = \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}s}\frac{\mathrm{d}x^\mu}{\mathrm{d}s} = \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}s}\left(U^\mu\frac{\mathrm{d}\tau}{\mathrm{d}s}\right) = \frac{\mathrm{d}U^\mu}{\mathrm{d}\tau}\left(\frac{\mathrm{d}\tau}{\mathrm{d}s}\right)^2 + U^\mu\frac{\mathrm{d}^2\tau}{\mathrm{d}s^2}$$
   and
   $$ \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}\tau}\ln\left(c\frac{\mathrm{d}\tau}{\mathrm{d}s}\right) = \frac{\mathrm{d}s}{\mathrm{d}\tau}\frac{\mathrm{d}^2\tau}{\mathrm{d}s^2}$$
   and therefore
   $$ \frac{\mathrm{d}\tilde{U}^\mu}{\mathrm{d}\tau} = \frac{\mathrm{d}U^\mu}{\mathrm{d}s} + U^\mu\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}\tau}\ln\left(c\frac{\mathrm{d}\tau}{\mathrm{d}s}\right)$$
2. To change the $\tilde{\Gamma}$ to $\Gamma$ you have to actually *calculate* the Christoffels for the 5D and 4D metric and express them in term of each other. It's tedious. The $F$ is, as usual, the curvature of the form $A$, i.e. $F_{\mu\nu} = \partial_\mu A_\nu - \partial_\nu A_\mu$, and it appears when you explicitly calculate the Christoffels (plausibility argument: The Christoffels are certain symmetric combinations of derivatives of the metric, in which $A$ appears, and $F$ is also a special (anti-)symmetric combination of derivatives of $A$).

Comment: So I'm reading that if you get the 4d EoM from the 5d EoM, in order to make it look like the Lorentz Law, you should identify $\dot{x}^5+A_\mu \dot{x}^\mu =\frac{q}{m}$ (see eqn 43.28 in http://www.blau.itp.unibe.ch/newlecturesGR.pdf). But, like you pointed out in a different post of mine, we really want to identify $U^5:=m \dot{x}^5=\frac{q}{m}$ (which makes sense - motion in 5th direction gives charge). How do I get rid of the $A_\mu \dot{x}^\mu$ term? Thanks.

Comment: @user11128: The dot in those notes refers to the derivative w.r.t. $s$, while the $U^5$ is the derivative of $x$ w.r.t. $\tau$.

Comment: Does that help to get rid of $A_\mu \dot{x}^\mu$? I see what you want to do: rewrite $\dot{x}^5+A_\mu \dot{x}^\mu = U^5$. But to my eyes, $U^5=\frac{dx^\mu}{d \tau}$ and I don't see how I can split that into the two terms above?

Comment: Am I understanding you correctly? I'm assuming $\dot{x}^5+A_\mu \dot{x}^\mu$ need to give a momentum in 5th direction (with respect to 5d proper time?) because the normal Kaluza Klein mantra is that momentum in extra direction becomes the electric charge. Is this the right idea? Thanks

Comment: @user11128: Divide the KK $\mathrm{d}s^2$ by $\mathrm{d}\tau^2$. You find $\frac{\mathrm{d}s^2}{\mathrm{d}\tau} = c^2 + \phi^2(A_\mu\dot{x}^\mu + \dot{x}^5)^2$. Recognize that this is $U_i U^i + U_5 U^5$, but from the viewpoint of the 4D metric, $U_5 = U^5$, so you get $U^5 = \dot{x}^5 + A_\mu\mathrm{d}x^\mu$.

Comment: Thanks but what is the meaning of $U^5$? Is it the velocity in the 5th direction with respect to 4d proper time? What does that even mean? And why (physically, not mathematically) is this the constant of motion rather than velocity in 5th direction with respect to 5d proper time?

Comment: @user11128: This isn't really related to the question you asked here, please ask *new* questions separately. However, I'll say this now: $U^5$ is the velocity *as seen* by the 4D spacetime. And while the velocity from the viewpoint of the 5D world may change in the fifth direction, the fifth degree of freedom is "frozen" from the 4D viewpoint, hence the velocity in that direction as seen by the 4D world is a constant of motion.